# Surface and css media queries

Tags: css, media-queries

We are in the process of converting a site to responsive and no matter what we do we cannot get the media queries to work on Microsoft surface we have tried the following

```
@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
 @-ms-viewport {
 width: 768px;
 height: 1024px;
  }
```

And it doesn't work has anything changed since 8.1 has been released to stop this working. Why Microsoft have to make us jump through leap holes. Even ipad accepts standard media queries why does surface have to be different and cause a headache.

Comment: Do you not just want to remove the `@media screen` and have `@-ms-viewport { width: device-width; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what your trying to do is

```
@-ms-viewport { width: device-width; }
```

But this code will target all "retina" type screens including the surface. [Source](http://mir.aculo.us/2012/11/28/the-ultimate-target-retina-screens-media-query/).

```
@media (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
       (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),
       (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
       (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
       (min-resolution: 144dpi),
       (min-resolution: 1.5dppx) {

/* Retina rules! */

}
```

Comment: I have tried this at the top and its still not being reflected now one problem I can see with our style sheets is that we have a media screen query with no sizes attached so the surface would find that first.

Comment: media (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
       (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),
       (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
       (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
       (min-resolution: 144dpi),
       (min-resolution: 1.5dppx) {

/* Retina rules! */
        div#defaultForm div#thirdColumn {
            visibility:hidden;
            visibility:collapse;
            display:none;
        }
}
 media screen{
    /* Standard HTML tags */   

 html, body {

So I persume that would overide the media what quiery would I used to ensure desktops are carted for

Comment: Yes you could use overriding rules inside this block.

Answer (score 2):

```
@media (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
       (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),
       (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
       (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
       (min-resolution: 144dpi),
       (min-resolution: 1.5dppx) and 
       (min-width: 1500px) and (max-width : 2000px) and
       @-ms-viewport {
{
 /** Surface Pro styles here **/
}
```

Works on Win10 Edge/IE11

Comment: Not sure if this works as CSS but SASS choked on it.